# No hot wire in switch box

Tags: switch, outdoor

I moved recently into a new house and had to replace an outdoor light and switch because both were dead. In the picture, the switch on the right is a 3-way switch that is wired and working fine. The left switch goes to the outdoor GFI switch and light. I replaced the GFI and wired it correctly but I’m still getting nothing. Everything works when I tie into the 3-way hot wire (but then the other 3-way switch has to stay on). Is there something I might be missing? Or do you think maybe the hot wire was cut somewhere? All the circuits from the breaker are good.

[image]

Comment: Not enough info, that switch may be on a switch leg from the receptacle , check for voltage at the receptacle location.

Comment: Did you press the reset button after you turned on the breaker to the GFCI receptacle that you installed? Some Gfci receptacles need a manual reset after the power was turned off and then back on.

Comment: I didn’t know about a switch leg. I’ll check when I get home in an hour or so. And yes I tried pressing reset on the GFCI.

Comment: There is no voltage at the receptacle location or the plug.

Comment: @jim when I wire the switch with live wire from the 3 way, everything works. But then it screws up the 3-way. My only thought is that there’s no power coming from the breaker but I wouldn’t even know where to begin on that as every breaker is working.

Comment: When you say "3-way hot wire", which wire are you referring to?

Comment: I was using the common wire from the 3-way. Had to leave the other 3-way switch turned on (Used painters tape) otherwise it would short out.

Comment: This could be a California 3 way with hot switched and traveller at both ends.

Comment: If that means I should have a constant hot, it’s not the case. When both of the two 3-ways are in a down position there is no hot in the pictured 3-way.

Comment: That looks like a plain switch. Why would there be 3 black wires going to it? They normally take 2.

Comment: The top two wires are what I assume go out to the GFI switch and outdoor light. They were tied together. I can’t figure out what the bottom wire is for as there is no live wire to the switch, GFI, or light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bought a wire tracer and was able to trace the hot wire to a switch receptacle upstairs, where it was taped off. Wired that to power and everything works. Thanks for all the responses/help![image]

Comment: Glad you were able to lick it!

Comment: Great work tracking this down! Be sure to give yourself a check-mark so someone in the future will know it's been fixed.